# Multilingual app in App Store; use two versions - or use apple localisation? (special case)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

I'm having a very unique dilemma regarding my app-submission to the iOS AppStore.

It's an app for kids between 1.5 and 3 years old, the idea behind the app is that a voice guides you through learning animal names and their sounds. Nothing revolutionary here. The app has always been in Swedish, but i've now added support for English (both the voice and texts).

So, how should i handle this when submitting to the AppStore? The default route would be localisation, but that will put to much faith on the device and it's settings. Also, i absolutely does not want to include any settings-menu in the app. If the customer download a swedish app, the app should be in swedish, regardless of the language-settings on the device.

My reasoning to exclude any settings in the app is that the target audience is small kids, and they should not have any other options then to play in the app. If i'd add flags to the start screen, the kids would click those and end up with a language they won't understand. Adding a language-setting in the "Settings.app", is an option. But does all parents/users know that there are even app-settings in there? Also, it's pretty bad if a swedish user buy the swedish version in the AppStore, but gets the english version on their iPad just because the iPads language is in english.

The other way to go about is to build targets and simply release another app to the AppStore, which is hardcoded to a specific language. The apps will have different names and the icon could differ slightly, such as background-colours and/or flags.

Pros and cons with localisation:

- + This is the preferred way by Apple
- + I can utilise the features of multilingual apps in the AppStore (reviews etc)

  + Customer gets all language when they buy the app (even though few, if none, will change language)

  - Parents need to be aware of that changing language on the iPad will change language on the App

  - A swedish user with an iPad in english will get the english version

  - It won't tell english users that there is an swedish version of the app available in the App Store.

  - All assets for all language will be in the same binary, binary could become rather big.

Pros and cons with two apps (different targets):

- + Very clear for the customer, downloading it in swedish and the app will remain in swedish, regardless of language on the iPad.
- + The extra promotion in the App Store won't hurt (customers see multiple language options in the App Store)
- + No settings needed
- + Only unique assets for the language, smaller binaries - faster downloads
- - Same icon for two apps (different names though) and adding flags represents countries rather than language.
- - Apple could ban my entire developer-account if they think that i'm spamming the App Store.
- - Customer need to buy two copies for two languages. Probably mute argument though, very few kids are multilingual at 2 years of age :)

Anyone with any similar experience that like to share? I'm really leaning towards both solutions here.

Comment: I'd go with the multiple app approach, the extra promotion worth it

Comment: @KirillKulakov Thanks for your input, would you use the same icon or change it's appearance a bit? Either via bg-color or maybe flags on the icon?

Comment: Choosing which language is used isn't done in the app itself, it's done in Settings/General/International. So if a user has set this to "Swedish", then all apps that are localised to Swedish will come up in Swedish, and all apps that are not will come in the first (or only) language they are localised to. (In MacOS X, the user can set an order of preference, like Swedish, then Italian, then Chinese, then English). You'd have a problem if parents want their apps in English, not Swedish, and the child wants this app in Swedish. I'd probably tend to have two apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that if a Swedish user has intentionally set their iPad language to English then they are used to their apps automatically defaulting to English due to localization, so I wouldn't expect them to be shocked about that.  If they know how to change their iPad language, then they should also have no problem switching the language in the Settings.app.  I think it would probably be a rare occasion also.

Apple isn't going to ban your account for having two similar apps on the App Store.  That being said, you will have a problem if you want to release your apps in more languages down the road, then you may look like you are spamming the App Store.

I would go with localization, you only have to keep track of one app.  I would probably add a note to the App Store listing stating the language can be changed and update your support website to let users know how to change the language.

Also, I think that your concerns about a start screen may be overblown. At your target age group (1.5-3 years),  It will be the parents who first start the application, popping up a English/Swedish banner immediately would allow them to set the language once and for all. Just my two cents.  Best of luck.

Comment: And what about the name of the App? Suppose the case I need my app be displayed in the AppStore with different names (depending on the current language the user has on his device). Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: of course its possible you can add localisation on Appstore as well.