# Best practice for country-specific app submission

Tags: ios, internationalization, app-store

After referring already discussed references -

https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/

https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/AppStoreTerritories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH18-SW1

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html

https://forums.developer.apple.com/community/app-frameworks/localization

[Multilingual app in App Store; use two versions - or use apple localisation? (special case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671455/multilingual-app-in-app-store-use-two-versions-or-use-apple-localisation-sp)

I understand below possibilities, but no solution! -

- Have one universal/generic app, and add internationalization and localization as per user language and manage features accordingly.
  (This is based on language of user, not country or store so would not serve my purpose)
- Have different apps with almost same features but having country specific changes (due to some country protocols/requirements), and release each for specific countries/store only. 
  (Possible solution, but will it carry a risk of app store spamming
  with similar apps even if those are in different store? and certain
  risk is to maintain separate code base)

What could be the best way to serve different countries with their slightly different requirement in the main app?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have one application and in which based first you fetch the location of user and based on that location you can load the assets or code based upon the country.